# posting to same page with ajax and php not working

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have a form that is supoused to post to same page, but it is not doing anything. I'm using same ajax script and php that I use in another page, the only difference is that this one has a form, but other than that everything works. But in this form page it is not working. Output is expected to show at the end of page; however, I'm not getting any errors in the console.
html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Contact Us</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- stylesheet for this form -->
    <link href="contact-stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm()
        {
            var params = "name=jorge&email=jorge@gmail.com";

            //send data to php form--------------------->
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

            }

            xmlhttp.open("POST", "contact.php", true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {

                    document.getElementById("outputtext").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.send(params);



        }       

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

      <div class="row">
          <div class="hero-unit" style="padding:20px 100px">
            <h1>Contact Us</h1>
            <p>aldkfjasdkfjaskdfasdfkasdkfjadsfjsdkfjaskfjasdkfjasjfaskdfjsdkfjsksdsdkjsd</p>       
        </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="my-form">
                <form class="form-horizontal" name="myForm"  >
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Text:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <textarea name="text" class="form-control" rows="7" placeholder="Text"></textarea>
              </div>    
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="validateForm()">Send</button>
            </div>
          </div>    
            </div> 
        </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div style="width:500px;heigth:350px;border:solid 1px brown">
                <h1>GOOGLE MAP HERE!</h1>
              </div>
             <!-- <img sytle="padding:0px 20px" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Miami+Downtown,Miami,FL&zoom=13&size=500x350&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7CMiami+Downtown,Miami,FL">                     -->
          </div>      
      </div>

        <div id="outputtext">
            <p>output text here!</p>
        </div>  
            <!-- display form result message here! -->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

php script

```
<?php

    echo "name: " . $_POST['name'] . " email: " . $_POST['email'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're submitting via `GET`:

```
            <form class="form-horizontal" name="myForm"  >
```

There's no `method="POST"`, therefore the browser defaults to a GET request, making $_POST be completely empty.  And your ajax code doesn't interrupt the standard submit behavior either, so it never gets a chance to send out its own POST request before the page shuts down.

Comment: Does that matter when it's JS that's making the request?

Comment: no. http is http. as long as js replicates what the form would've done, there's no way for the browser to tell it was an ajax header (there is an X- header used for ajax, but since it's http, it's easy to forge/omit).

Comment: I had a method="post" in my form, and I removed it b/c it didn't make any difference. I'm still not getting anything back with or w/o it